# Pattern validation in angular 7

Tags: regex, typescript, angular7

I have a contact number field in my **Angular 7** form.I used 'form builder' and 'validators.pattern' for validation.In the HTML, I tried two ways to determine whether there was an error ,but both didnt work.

TypeScript:
    `mobnumPattern = "^[6-9][0-9]{9}$";
this.myForm = this.formbuilder.group({
contact_no: ['', [Validators.required,Validators.pattern(this.mobnumPattern)]],}
)`

1.When I used below HTML, validation always shows true

```
*ngIf="((myForm.controls['contact_no'].touched) && (myForm.controls['contact_no'].hasError(pattern)))"
```

2.When I used below HTML, validation always shows false

```
*ngIf="((myForm.controls['contact_no'].touched) && (myForm.controls['contact_no'].errors.pattern))"
```

Any idea how to solve this?.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets go over both the cases you have mentioned.

> 1.When I used below HTML, validation always shows true

I tried recreating the issue in stackblitz but it is always false unlike what you said. Anyway the check `myForm.controls['contact_no'].hasError(pattern)` returns false since `hasError()` is [expecting a string as its parameter,](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControlDirective#hasError) but pattern here is undefined.

Use this to check if the form control has pattern validation errors.

```
*ngIf="((myForm.controls['contact_no'].touched)&& myForm.controls['contact_no'].hasError('pattern')))"
```

> 2.When I used below HTML, validation always shows false

`myForm.controls['contact_no'].errors` will be null if the form control does not have any validation errors. So when checking `myForm.controls['contact_no'].errors.pattern` in the template will throw an error and return undefined. Use a safe navigation operator to protect against a view render failure if the myForm.controls['contact_no'].errors is null.

Like this:

```
*ngIf="((myForm.controls['contact_no'].touched) && (myForm.controls['contact_no'].errors?.pattern)"
```

I have made a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c5hzge) with the above mentioned fix. Check the link to see the working demo.